# What is MLM & NSP loss function

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer, objective-functions, bert

Two objective functions are used during the BERT language
model pretraining step.

The first one is masked language
model (MLM) that randomly masks
15% of the
input tokens and the objective is to predict the vocabulary

The second objective
is the next sentence prediction (NSP) task. This is a binary
classification task for predicting whether two sentences are
subsequent in the original text.

I am looking for such objective function as mathematical definition.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/40590/1794, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/160345/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).